# how to hide bottomtabs when a route 2 levels deep is displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

so when a certain screen is displayed, i want the bottom tabbar to disappear. 
I am using react navigation.

when The insight detail adjustment screen is active, I want the bottomtabs to disappear. 
Currently noting is working, only when I type bottomtabs {visible:false} inside the bottomtab navigator it works, but I need it nested one level deeper.

```
const incidentStack = createStackNavigator({
  'incident Overview': {
    screen: incidentOverview,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: 'Pointbreak',
      headerLeft: ( 
      <TouchableOpacity onPress ={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
        <Image style={{marginLeft: 10}} source={require('../img/menu.png')}></Image>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  },
  'insight detail adjustment': {
      screen: InsightDetailAdjustment,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          header: (
            <HeaderTitleInsightDetailAdjustment navigation={navigation}/>
          ),
          bottomTabs: {
            visible: false
          }
      })
  }
})





const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Insights: {
        screen: InsightsStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Icon name='chart-line-variant' size={30} color={tintColor}/>
          ),

        }
      },
      Incidents: {
        screen: incidentStack,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          tabBarVisible: () => (
            if(navigation.navigate('incident detail adjustment'){
              return false
            }else{
              return true
            })
          ),
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Icon name='bullhorn-outline' size={30} color={tintColor}/>
          ),
        })
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
InsightsStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  // hides tabNavigation starting from 2 screen deep in InsightsStack Stack
  let tabBarVisible = true;
  if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    tabBarVisible = false;
  }

  return {
    tabBarVisible
  };
};
```